# how to remove previous marker automatically before adding new marker

Tags: leaflet, angularjs, cordova

I am using ui-leaflet on my ionic 1 mobile app which is the same as angular-leaflet-directive shown in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DepJeg?p=preview) link.

I am getting the user location and adding it to the marker and circle in the map, the issue i am having is that has the user moves their location is updated and therefore adding a new marking which then spans the maps which is not what I want. 
What I am trying to achieve is that has a new marker is added or before a new marker is added, It should remove the old marker. How can I do this please? Below is my code and what I have tried

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['leaflet-directive'])

.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'leafletData'];

function myCtrl($scope, leafletData) {
  var location = {
    lat: -33.8830,
    lng: 151.2166
  };

  var mainMarker = {
    lat: location.lat,
    lng: location.lng,
    focus: true,
    draggable: false
  };

  var vm = angular.extend(this, {
    center: {
      lat: location.lat,
      lng: location.lng,
      zoom: 17
    },
    markers: {
      mainMarker: angular.copy(mainMarker)
    },
    defaults: {
      zoomControl: false
    },
    tiles: {
      url: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    }
  });

  function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
    var marker;

    leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
      /* does not work in removing the old marker */

      if (marker) { // check
        map.removeControl(marker); // remove
      }

      var options = {
        icon: {
          icon: 'fa-certificate',
          prefix: 'fa',
          shape: 'square',
          markerColor: 'green'
        }
      };

      marker = L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
      //.bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

      L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);


    });
  }

  function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message, e.code);
  }

  leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
    L.easyButton({
      position: 'bottomright',
      states: [{
        icon: 'fa fa-location-arrow fa-lg',
        onClick: function(btn, map) {
          map.locate({
            setView: true,
            maxZoom: 16,
            watch: true,
            enableHighAccuracy: true
          });
          map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound); //see if it is possible to pass the map has a perimetrr
          map.on('locationerror ', onLocationError);
        }
      }]
    }).addTo(map);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`map.removeControl(marker);` should be `map.removeLayer(marker);`

It never fires though because `marker` is undefined. I don't use Angular but it seems like you need to do something to have `marker` in scope. This may be the wrong approach in Angular, but this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9uux28j/14/) works and should get you in the right direction.

Comment: I have tried both of them before asking the question

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/baako/g5ku6due/2/) try this on your mobile phone or tablet. Move around a little you will see the marker just keeps adding and the old marker doesnt get remove

Comment: It seems to have something to do with Angular scoping - this fiddle works: https://jsfiddle.net/a9uux28j/14/

Comment: can you put your jsfiddle link in the answer so I can mark this has the answer. Thank you

Comment: ok, updated with the link

Answer (score 1):

It's because in your code, you declare `var marker` but you don't instantiate it before your `if (marker)` condition. Therefore your condition is always false because `marker` is undefined.

You should replace

```
function onLocationFound(e) {
  var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
  var marker;
  leafletData.getMap().then(function (map) {

    if (marker) { // check
      map.removeLayer(marker); // remove
      map.removeControl(marker); // remove
    }

    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
      .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
  });
}
```

with

```
function onLocationFound(e) {
  var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

  leafletData.getMap().then(function (map) {
    map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
      // Remove all layers except the background (tilelayer)
      // EDIT: and the main marker with the custom property
      if (!(layer instanceof L.TileLayer) && layer.options.myCustomProperty != 'myMainMarker')) {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
      }
    });

    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
      .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
  });
}
```

which iterates over all layers and removes them from the map (except the background tile layer).

EDIT: to avoid your main marker from being removed, you must find a way to identify it, so I've added a custom property to it, and a additional check in the condition above.

```
var mainMarker = {
    lat: location.lat,
    lng: location.lng,
    focus: true,
    draggable: false,
    // Added custom property
    myCustomProperty: 'myMainMarker'
};
```

That's not ideal. The best way would be to save the dynamic marker (+ precision circle) and to remove them specifically.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g5ku6due/7/

Comment: Thanks @thibautg it does what I want it to do except that it has removed the default marker which is not what I was expecting.

Comment: To avoid your main marker from being removed, you must find a way to identify it, so I've edited the answer to add a custom property to it, and a additional check in the condition. That's not ideal. The best way would be to save the dynamic marker (+ precision circle) and to remove them specifically. But it does the trick.

Comment: I think that @Marc Fister's comment on the [other answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/254533/51507) is better, because the marker is correctly instantiated https://jsfiddle.net/a9uux28j/14/

Answer (score 1):

```
home = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                        Log.d("mytag ", "current latlong is------" + lat + "," + lng);
                        marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home).title("Here lives "));
                        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(home, 10));
```

and add this below code

```
                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                    marker = null;
                }
```